# Separating the concepts of deployment and release — benefits for enterprise apps

Tags: deployment, release-management

I was taking the PluralSight course with the title “azure-devops-continuous-delivery-release-pipelines”  and it makes a big deal out of (ie spends a lot of time talking about) separating the release and deployment concepts, and adding features behind feature flags.

Where Deployment = binaries in production; Released = feature available to end users in production.

For enterprise applications, that seems to be very rarely useful.  Features are generally desired as quickly as possible, and are only occasional delayed for regulatory or other business reason.  The general concern is not getting them done in time, not them being used prematurely. And of course bug fixes are almost always “fix now”.

It seems to me that the concept (and cost associated with implementing it) is better suited to SASS application, not in house custom application.

Is there any benefit for it in house custom application, beyond the once a year “allow this after the 15th”?

Comment: The premise of the question seems to greatly underplay those regulatory and business reasons -- ultimately many businesses are heavily dependent upon their internal software (and even more dependent on the data that it stores/handles) that just a few hours of downtime or a high-severity bug which breaks its core functionality could lose millions, or cause major reputational damage, or both.   In general, the more important a bit of software is to the business, the greater impact of any problems, and more important to try mitigating risks around software changes.

Comment: This question is unclear. The reference to Pluralsight is not available to people like me without an account at their site (and no intent to create one). So I cannot tell what this "big deal" really is you mentioned. Also, I don't see their position about feature flags. It is also unclear if you talk about feature flags to control what goes into a release, or feature flags to control which features are available after deployment. ...

Comment: ... Moreover, it is very unclear to what you have in mind by "not separating releases and deployment" - I know this as "Continuous Deployment", which is a process for software systems like Facebook or Google search, so definitely not "Enterprise" or "Inhouse" software, quite the opposite. So please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: @BenCottrell: how does separating the concepts of release and deployment prevent either bugs or downtime?

Comment: @DocBrown: changed the PluralSight to just the title, I’m not shilling for them and don’t expect anyone to sign up for anything, features after deployment. Not sure what it would mean to have features in a release that weren’t part of the deployment.

Comment: This is not a clarification of my questions.

Comment: @DocBrown: I guess I don’t understand your request for clarification.

Comment: @jmoreno: for me, the concept of a release is a development task, and deployment is an administrative task. These are inherently different things by definition. Now you are promoting something like "not separating releases and deployment" in inhouse development. I have not the slightest idea what that should mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: @DocBrown I don't know where you got your definition. But putting "deployment vs release" into google spits out multiple links( https://www.simform.com/blog/deployment-vs-release/ https://www.bmc.com/blogs/software-deployment-vs-release/ https://waydev.co/deployment-vs-release/ https://beyond-agility.com/deployment-vs-release/ ) that use exactly opposite definition. Deployment is making changes in production environment (eg. copying binaries). And is purely technical. Release is making changes available to users. And is mainly business decission.

Comment: @Euphoric: actually, your first link says exactly what I wrote. To use your words: "Deployment=copying binaries to production = administrative task" (opposed to development task). "Release=collecting code changes / features / bugfixes into a version which might be deployed next = task for a software developer" (and yes, this is usually triggered by business needs / decisions).

Comment: ... but the crucial problem with this question is: the OP did not write what they meant by those terms (or by "not separating them"), just referrring to some Pluralsight course which we cannot access here. This leaves us guessing around what this question is about. I think the question should be closed if the OP does not add an example soon.

Comment: I guess. Once again, good question soiled by lack of proper definitions in our profession. Its like doctors having multiple conflicting names for body parts and not agreeing what is right. /sad

Comment: @Euphoric: it is a question which might have some potential to become a good one, but currently I think it is soiled by the refusal of the OP to give a better explanation and/or examples what they have in mind. The whole question is too vague, that's not an issue of our profession.

Comment: @DocBrown: I am not refusing to do anything, I’m dealing with my life as best I can.  Yes, I asked a question, that doesn’t mean I expect answers in 5 seconds nor that I will watch it 24/7 until I get an answer that satisfies me.  This is software engineering, not stack overflow, I don’t need the question answered instantly and would actually prefer any answer to be delayed and better rather than faster and less well thought out.  I also am not advocating or promoting anything, I asked a question, nothing more.

Comment: @jmoreno A lot of bugs won't appear until changes are deployed into a real environment, so the idea of deployment without a release is to use test environments whose state mimics production as closely as possible (including all the stuff that wouldn't be suitable in a dev environment, such as realistic data, extra layers of security, configuration and dependencies) as part of the dev workflow before even merging the code.  By allowing the "real" deployment process to happen from Dev branches into a prod-like env we can get much earlier visibility of bugs which wouldn't otherwise appear in dev.

Comment: @jmoreno: sorry, but all I see are very half-hearted attempts to improve the question. It stays as unclear to me as it was from the beginning.

Comment: @DocBrown: and your confusion remains just as confusing to me. I provided definitions as requested, I don’t understand what you don’t understand, and so am unable to provide any clarification to you.

Comment: @BenCottrell: the recommendation was to put them into production, but turned off by feature flags. I certainly understand the benefit of realistic test environments.

Comment: @jmoreno Sorry, i was responding to the question in your comment above: *"how does separating the concepts of release and deployment prevent either bugs or downtime?"* -- I wasn't commenting on feature flags (a separate issue IMO).    Although the benefit of splitting release and deployment is the ability to do deployment at any stage in development, including when the changes are still incomplete/unstable.   Even if the feature is toggled off in production, it should be tested as early as possible in a production-like environment ideally.

Comment: @jmoreno: what you call a "definition" arew only two terse half-sentences with no useful example and probably not reflecting what your original source provided (since you wrote they "spend a lot of time talking about"). But when these "definitions" is all what you kept from the source, then I think I finally understand your confusion: the term "Release" is vague and ambiguous. We often use this term synomously for "creating a version for production, including a certain feature set" (and hence "making features available to the end user as soon as that version gets installed for them").  ....

Comment: ... but it seems there is another definition (which is quite unusual to me): "releasing = activating a feature by using a feature toggle *after* the software was deployed.  Since I don't have access to your original PluralSight course, I cannot tell you if they really meant that second definition, or this is just a misunderstanding of yours.

Comment: @DocBrown: Yes, that is what I (and they) meant, and it was right there in my original question "adding features behind feature flags.".  The idea of generally doing that instead of only when required by business rules (i.e. discount starts on the 1st, start calculating discount on the 1st), was exactly my question.  Others seem to have understood it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree, the idea of feature flagged "features" which are deployed to to live but then "released" with a switch has been over sold.

However that doesnt mean theres no concepts in the bundle you can't use and get benefits from.

1. Versioned releases.

   ie. You have more than one version live at the same time. This allows a smooth transition to new versions, where some internal work practices might not have been held over 1 to 1. (ie. people have to be persuaded to change the way they work)
2. Canary releases

   ie. Only a proportion of users uses the new release and you can roll back at any time. Super useful for "live testing" to see if what was asked for is really what is needed.
3. Continuous deployment and short lived/small features.

   Even if you don't hide them behind feature flags, having multiple small updates over time, and getting people used to the idea of gradual iterative improvements vs "the big deploy" has a whole bunch of benefits.

You can achieve these things and make development easier and better without going the whole hog of having a feature flag for every feature, multiple features in flight at the same time and the associated complexity

Comment: Not versioned releases, but supporting an api that regularly versions (every year or two) with a possible overlap (supporting old format and new for 2-3 months) is what I was thinking of as the occasional valid use case. Canary releases in house would be kind strange to me.

Comment: I think you are saying that the concept has some value when…

Comment: What I would say is, the things people try to achieve with feature flags, they have value. "feature flags" overall are problematic, but yeah you would have to write an essay.

Answer (score 7):

It is absolutely correct to consider whether "best practices" and similar advice are even applicable in your situations. For example, lots of design patterns and principles make a lot of sense for libraries, but not so much for applications. [12 Factor](https://12factor.net/) style advice like distinguishing release and deployment concepts are mostly applicable in a SaaS/web application/microservice context, less so for in-house desktop applications.

Instead of working backwards from supposedly best practices, consider starting with a problem you want to solve. The root cause, typically, is that humans are fallible. Features might have bugs, or developers might not understand needs properly.

For example, this means we might want to let end users test a change in advance, before it's properly rolled out. This is not about artificially delaying rollout, but about facilitating conversations with subject matter experts: "hey, I fixed the thing, can you tell me if it looks correct?". Ideally, we'd be able to create a test deployment, and if everything is fine deploy that release for everyone. That is easier if we have a clear release vs deployment distinction. Or we guard the new functionality behind a feature toggle that we only enable for our beta users.

Inevitably, faults occur in production. It is often desirable to roll back to a known-good version. Maybe you have an archive of old releases and their deployment config, maybe you do GitOps and can revert a branch to an older commit. But if the problem only relates to one feature, a rollback could also revert unrelated changes. Feature flags mitigate risks by making it easier to turn off potentially-buggy behaviour in a more surgical manner.

Comment: "Feature flags mitigate risks by making it easier to turn off potentially-buggy behaviour in a more surgical manner" _only_ if you have tested the system with all combinations of feature flag settings. Otherwise its better to roll back properly

Comment: @Ewan It is not necessary to test all combinations. The decision is between continuing with the current known-buggy configuration, versus using a less tested configuration that disables the known-buggy features, versus reverting to an earlier release that lacks the feature entirely, but also lacks other features and bugfixes released since then. All of these are bad, but the risks can be weighed for each specific situation. Also, if time permits, that new configuration could also receive some testing. You don't have to use feature flags, but they give you more options to respond to problems.

Comment: The difference is that if you have allowed multiple feature flags you have multiple states to "roll back" to. If you are deploying "all or nothing" releases you just have one state to roll back to. which going to be pretty sure that passed testing and has been live for some time. Is that "bad"? well your new release is delayed, but all releases are fully tested and followed whatever auditing processes you have. You are being more careful about what you have live.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by “That is easier if we have a clear release vs deployment distinction.”, instead of a distinction between release and deployment, that seems to me to be a call for a good test environment.

Comment: @jmoreno Yes, being able to have test and staging deployments is exactly what I'm getting at. That is, we can take the same codebase and deploy it either in prod for all users, or spin up a (disposable) test deployment. But this requires that we have a distinction between “I've written this code” and “everyone starts using it”, and it requires the codebase to be generic enough that test deployments become possible (e.g. no hard-coded hostnames in a web app, no hardcoded install paths for a desktop app).

Answer (score 3):

It's more about feature size/complexity than urgency. You pretty much always want to deploy a new feature as soon as practical. Something that takes a single developer a few days or less you wouldn't typically want to release with a feature flag. Something that requires multiple teams multiple weeks you would.

What happens if you don't is all the developers test their parts in isolation, then when everyone thinks they're ready you try to integrate all the parts in one big bang. Inevitably, things break, and so you panic trying to fix the integrated feature as quickly as possible. Or you back it out, try and solve it separately, then try to integrate again and something different breaks.

In that sort of situation, the benefits of using a feature flag far outweigh the costs.

Comment: So integration across systems or micro-services might be an example of where you would deploy it, but not make it immediately available. And if you were doing that a lot, you’d want to keep the concepts very clearly distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Separating deployment from release is necessary if you want to adopt Continuous Delivery and Trunk-Based Development. With these approaches, you end up with features that aren't finished yet being integrated into main trunk and deployed into production (or included in deployment package for non-SAAS).

With feature toggles, it becomes possible for every developer to integrate into shared trunk daily, possibly even multiple times a day, even if the whole feature might take many days to develop, integrate and test.

This really piggy-backs on values of CD and TBD. If you consider these to be valuable, then feature toggles to hide unfinished features become a necessity. And from there, you get into separating deployment from releases.

For example, imagine a situation where developer is building new feature. He has commited some initial changes, made new APIs, but hasn't finalized work on database yet. Then, a critical bug is found and needs to be fixed ASAP. It is fixed, but then you either have to release with incomplete feature. Or wait for the feature to be finished. If the feature is hidden behind a flag, it becomes a non-issue. There are of course various branching strategies that try to avoid this by having different versions in different branches. But then that becomes a topic of TBD vs feature branches.

Comment: I would argue that its automated testing which enables daily merges to master, not feature toggles. Its the guarantee of testing which allows you to merge and know you haven't broken anything, regardless of whether or how the feature is hidden.

Comment: @Ewan There are multiple prerequisites to make continous delivery work. Both automated testing to ensure integrated code works and hiding unfinished features are necessary. I'm sure there are few more I can't think of right now. Feture toggles are necessary, so that unfinished features are not made available to use before they are deemed safe to use.

Comment: if your feature is unsafe, then it shouldn't have a flag which can potentially be flipped to on. If you just want to check in incomplete features, they can have passing tests but no entry point from the rest of the code. no need for toggles

Comment: @Ewan How can incomplete features be tested if they don't have an entrypoint? Sure, one can do unit tests, but there are so many more testing methods I'd like to apply before making the decision to deploy a new feature.

Comment: @Ewan There is gradient of "unsafe". Of course you don't want to even commit changes that are "breaks down the system unsafe". But at some point, the feature becomes mature enough and it becomes "'we don't want innocent eyes of our customers to see this feature we are preparing for them in secret' unsafe". At that point, it is perfectly acceptable to have feature available to testers or select few users.

Comment: I think you are mixing terms here. are you feature toggling on/off to enable daily merges, separate release and deploy, canary releasing or having a closed beta version? If the feature is incomplete and you just want the merge, then the end to end tests are going to fail and beta users can't use it regardless. The other three are beyond the scope of my comment. But I think its illustrative of feature flagism in general. Yeah you can do a lot of stuff with it..... if you ignore combinatorial testing of all your flags.

Comment: It's _not_ necessary (and I'd argue undesirable) to hide part-completed work behind feature toggles to do TBD. You can continuously integrate and deploy without it, but you do have to be thoughtful and disciplined about how you slice the work that's being delivered. That's also how you get to a point where you _don't_ have to down tools on in-flight work to fix a bug, because you'll finish the current deliverable slice and be able to pick up whatever's next _soon_.